# UNITY - Working with AssetBundle -> Unload

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

In my code I have several snippets like the one below with different purpose. In the start() method I added the following code "AssetBundle.UnloadAllAssetBundles(false);". When I run the application sometimes it runs without error and sometimes it runs with the following error "can't be loaded because another AssetBundle with the same files is already loaded.".

```
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(webRequest.error);
            }
            else
            {
                AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(webRequest);

                GameManager.Instance.bundleListCues = new List<Sprite>(bundle.LoadAllAssets<Sprite>());
                if (bundle == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to download AssetBundle!");
                    yield break;
                }
                bundle.Unload(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `can't be loaded because another AssetBundle with the same files is already loaded` .. sounds pretty self-explanatory to me apparently you are trying to load the same bundle file twice .. sometimes it works but sometimes it conflicts -> sounds like a timing/race condition

Comment: @derHugo As well? Would it be like execution order?